# How to start to implement foundation 3 css framework?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am planning to use foundation 3 css framework, but has no idea where should I start.
I got the jpeg mock up from designer, which design from scatch. Does the mock up need to be designed based on the founcation's grid?

Answer (score 0):

Best if you take a look at the documentation for Foundation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

Comment: is this website layout suitable to use  foundation?[link](http://www.tresixtee.com)

Comment: Any layout can be handled with Foundation. You have all the tools for creating the layout you want :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily have to be designed by keeping the grid in mind. Any thing can be achieved with the grid system. This is basically way to create a responsive website and also helps in maintaining uniformity through out the page.

I also suggest the following:

1) get a template you like form the foundation 3 website and then start with that. Try to see how the html structure is and then.
2) try to change the backgrounds, colors by adding properties inside app.css (ITS BEST IF YOU DO NOT MAKE CHANGES TO foundation.css file).
3)Use tools like firebug or the inbuilt "inspect element" in browsers to find out which css property is being used and you can change it. 
4)You need to explore it for atleast a couple of hours.

cheers!!